# OpenSSL not enabled on apache 2.4 Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, php7

I'm running php 7.1.10 on windows 10, so far if I do `php -m` I see openssl in extensions list, I copied `libssh2.dll`, `ssleay32.dll`, `libeay32.dll` to `apache/bin` and `Windows/System32` restarted `apache` several times, but OpenSSL is still disabled.

Did I miss something in configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the run time variable **OPENSSL_CONF** is set.

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\conf\openssl.cnf
```

In the httpd.conf you would need some extra line (remove the # if it's there):

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

and

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Be sure you have created your OpenSSL certificate when you will edit the httpd-ssl.conf file.

**Extra step for the certificate**

```
openssl req -new -out server.csr
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.key
openssl x509 -in server.csr -out server.cert -req -signkey server.key -days 365
```

And you move the server.key and server.cert to the conf folder. *(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\conf)*

Comment: Thanks for update actually problem was in dll files which I had to copy in System32 and Apache from php folder, after moving them and restart of Windows all works fine.